# How to display days of next month on selection change of a Combobox which is holding list of days of a particular month

Tags: c#, wpf

I have 2 comboboxes. The First combobox displays the month and the second combobox displays the days of the month selected.

Suppose the month selected is Jan and day selected is 31. Now if the user clicks the keyboard down arrow, then the next day should be displayed.
i.e. Month Combo should select Feb and Day combo should select 1. How can I achieve this?

When the user changes the month, I am binding the actual number of days for the month selected. I am not finding the proper event which will trigger when user tries to cross the combobox limits.
i.e. When user clicks down arrow on day 31, how can I track the limit of the combobox values are crossed, so that I can populate the days of next month?

Comment: Are you binding to dependency properties?

Comment: I don't think there is any event for keypressing in a combobox. You could probably add extra items though, add a (previous) item before the days and a (next) item after the days and handle selection of those. Not a perfect solution, but it should work at least.

Comment: No I am not binding to dependency property. I have an approach for the above query but just wanted to find out the best approach. As user is free to scroll down to any day of any month, it is quite an overhead to trace the correct selected day to populate the correct month. Any approach ???

Answer (score 0):

One idea is to add an extra and invisible day to days combobox and when it's selected change the selected month.

This is your viewModel (dataContext of your view)

```
public class ViewModel : DependencyObject
{
    public ViewModel()
    {
        for (int i = 0; i < 12; i++)
        {
            Months.Add(new Month(i+1, 31, this));//this is simplified
        }
        SelectedMonth = Months.First();
    }
    //Months Observable Collection
    private ObservableCollection<Month> _months = new ObservableCollection<Month>();
    public ObservableCollection<Month> Months { get { return _months; } }
    //SelectedMonth Dependency Property
    public Month SelectedMonth
    {
        get { return (Month)GetValue(SelectedMonthProperty); }
        set { SetValue(SelectedMonthProperty, value); }
    }
    public static readonly DependencyProperty SelectedMonthProperty =
        DependencyProperty.Register("SelectedMonth", typeof(Month), typeof(ViewModel), new UIPropertyMetadata(null));
}
```

This is you Month class

```
public class Month : DependencyObject
{
    public Month(int number, int count, ViewModel parent)
    {
        _parent = parent;
        Number = number;
        Days.Add(new Day { IsLastDayOfMonth = false, IsFirstDayOfMonth = true });
        for (int i = 0; i < count; i++)
        {
            Days.Add(new Day { 
                Number = i + 1, 
                IsLastDayOfMonth = false, 
                IsFirstDayOfMonth = false });
        }
        Days.Add(new Day { IsLastDayOfMonth = true, IsFirstDayOfMonth = false });
        SelectedDay = Days[1];//first is empty so by default day1 is selected
    }
    ViewModel _parent;

    //Number Dependency Property
    public int Number
    {
        get { return (int)GetValue(NumberProperty); }
        set { SetValue(NumberProperty, value); }
    }
    public static readonly DependencyProperty NumberProperty =
        DependencyProperty.Register("Number", typeof(int), typeof(Month), new UIPropertyMetadata(1));

    //Days Observable Collection
    private ObservableCollection<Day> _days = new ObservableCollection<Day>();
    public ObservableCollection<Day> Days { get { return _days; } }

    //SelectedDay Dependency Property
    public Day SelectedDay
    {
        get { return (Day)GetValue(SelectedDayProperty); }
        set { SetValue(SelectedDayProperty, value); }
    }
    public static readonly DependencyProperty SelectedDayProperty =
        DependencyProperty.Register("SelectedDay", typeof(Day), typeof(Month),
        new UIPropertyMetadata(null, (d, e) =>
        {
            var viewModel = ((Month)d)._parent;
            if (((Day)e.NewValue).IsLastDayOfMonth)
            {
                var selMonth = viewModel.Months.FirstOrDefault(x => x.Number == ((Month)d).Number + 1);
                if (selMonth == null || selMonth.Number == 1) return;
                viewModel.SelectedMonth = selMonth;
                viewModel.SelectedMonth.SelectedDay =
                    viewModel.SelectedMonth.Days[1];//first real day of month
            }
            else if (((Day)e.NewValue).IsFirstDayOfMonth)
            {
                var selMonth = viewModel.Months.FirstOrDefault(x => x.Number == ((Month)d).Number - 1);
                if (selMonth == null) return;
                viewModel.SelectedMonth = selMonth;
                viewModel.SelectedMonth.SelectedDay = 
                    viewModel.SelectedMonth.Days[
                    viewModel.SelectedMonth.Days.Count - 2];//last real day of month
            }
        }));
}
```

This is your Day class

```
    //Number Dependency Property
    public int Number
    {
        get { return (int)GetValue(NumberProperty); }
        set { SetValue(NumberProperty, value); }
    }
    public static readonly DependencyProperty NumberProperty =
        DependencyProperty.Register("Number", typeof(int), typeof(Day), new UIPropertyMetadata(1));
    //IsLastDayOfMonth Dependency Property
    public bool IsLastDayOfMonth
    {
        get { return (bool)GetValue(IsLastDayOfMonthProperty); }
        set { SetValue(IsLastDayOfMonthProperty, value); }
    }
    public static readonly DependencyProperty IsLastDayOfMonthProperty =
        DependencyProperty.Register("IsLastDayOfMonth", typeof(bool), typeof(Day), new UIPropertyMetadata(false));
    public bool IsFirstDayOfMonth
    {
        get { return (bool)GetValue(IsFirstDayOfMonthProperty); }
        set { SetValue(IsFirstDayOfMonthProperty, value); }
    }
    public static readonly DependencyProperty IsFirstDayOfMonthProperty =
        DependencyProperty.Register("IsFirstDayOfMonth", typeof(bool), typeof(Day), new UIPropertyMetadata(false));
```

And this is your xaml:

```
    <ComboBox ItemsSource="{Binding SelectedMonth.Days}"
              SelectedItem="{Binding SelectedMonth.SelectedDay}">
        <ComboBox.ItemTemplate>
            <DataTemplate>
                <TextBlock Text="{Binding Number}" x:Name="textblock"/>
                <DataTemplate.Triggers>
                    <DataTrigger Binding="{Binding IsLastDayOfMonth}" Value="True">
                        <Setter TargetName="textblock" Property="Visibility" Value="Collapsed"/>
                    </DataTrigger>
                </DataTemplate.Triggers>
            </DataTemplate>
        </ComboBox.ItemTemplate>
    </ComboBox>
```

Comment: Thanks for the solution. The solution is handled to work for down arrow click on the selected Month's last day. It is not handled for up arrow click on selected Month's first day.

Comment: It's just the same. Add IsFirstDayOfMonth, copy paste some logic and modify the indices a bit and it's good to go.

Comment: I have posted the code that i have modified to get the FirstDay of Month, please let me know where I am going wrong.

Comment: The problem was viewModel.SelectedMonth = new Month(...) it creates a new Month therefore SelectedDay = Day[0] and callback is executed. creating a new Month and so on. stackoverflow! exception. I changed a few things and it's working now.

Comment: Thanks Bizz. When the window is loaded for the first time, if up arrow is clicked I dont see the last day of the previous month loading.

Comment: I didn't get that. You mean the Combobox becomes empty when presses up on day1,month1 ?

Comment: Yes. I meant when combobox becomes empty when presses up on day1, month1. I guess adding an else part(when SelectedMonth = null) in the SelectedDayProperty DP will solve the problem.

Comment: Ok. I changed it again. I know you can't edit my post, but We are supposed to help each other not write each other's codes!